# scala: Specifying method type for currying

Tags: scala, currying

The following method type describes a function that passes configuration info and data to a method. Each method of this type can perform a different function.

```
  type FTDataReductionProcess =(PipelineConfiguration,RDDLabeledPoint) => RDDLabeledPoint
```

The above works fin.

But what I would like to do is different. I want to add the configuration to the method first, and then later add the data. So I need currying.

I thought this would work:

```
  type FTDataReductionProcess =(PipelineConfiguration)(RDDLabeledPoint) => RDDLabeledPoint
```

but this causes a compilation error

> Cannot resolve symbol RDDLabeledPoint

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a function that takes a `PipelineConfiguration` and returns another function that takes an `RDDLabeledPoint` and returns an `RDDLabeledPoint`.

- What is the domain? `PipelineConfiguration`.
- What is the return type? A "function that takes `RDDLP` and returns `RDDLP`", that is: `(RDDLabeledPoint => RDDLabeledPoint)`.

All together:

```
type FTDataReductionProcess = 
  (PipelineConfiguration => (RDDLabeledPoint => RDDLabeledPoint))
```

Since `=>` is right-associative, you can also write:

```
type FTDataReductionProcess = 
  PipelineConfiguration => RDDLabeledPoint => RDDLabeledPoint
```

By the way: the same works for function literals too, which gives a nice concise syntax. Here is a shorter example to demonstrate the point:

```
scala> type Foo = Int => Int => Double // curried function type
defined type alias Foo

scala> val f: Foo = x => y => x.toDouble / y     // function literal
f: Foo = $$Lambda$1065/1442768482@54089484

scala> f(5)(7)  // applying curried function to two parameters
res0: Double = 0.7142857142857143
```

Comment: as always, it was my thinking that was flawed. Functional programming if a whole new mindset

Comment: If you took a brief look at Haskell, this syntax would seem even more natural. In Haskell, you usually declare multi-argument functions like this: `foo :: a -> b -> c -> returnType`.